# Where has Notepad++ hidden my file?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, file-recovery

I have spent all day making notes on the planning of a two week task. As I came to the end of the day I couldn't save the file over to a Network Drive, so I closed Notepad++ and re-opened using administrator privileges. Notepad++ failed to remember which files were open, and seems to have deleted the original important file, along with a bunch of others, on my desktop.

I had been saving it all day to my 'local' (i.e. network profile) desktop:

```
\\-USERNAME-\Users$\-username-\Desktop\Testing.txt
```

And I closed and re-opened the application to attempt to save it here:

```
Y:\Project - -NAME-\Integration Testing\Strategy
```

As the file was not open in the application, I began to go digging, however I have been unable to locate it.

**Do you please know if Notepad++ will have moved this file somewhere obscure** (AppData, whatever the Windows for 'root' is, etc), **if it will be possible to recover it *without using a backup*** (which I have asked for but may take a long time) **or whether I have lost it forever**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On my install **Notepad++** saves a backup below location

`C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup\`

You can find this under Settings → Preferences → Backup
& there should be your backup path.

If you cannot find it there try scanning the location you did previously saved it (your desktop) with *Recuva*.  I have had success with file recovery with that program.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. It turns out this was an issue with the Windows environment- to prevent 'forgetful' sysadmins the Admin/root account moves all files which come into it's ownership into the local Administrator profile. That's where I found the file, if it helps anyone else. Tedious, but less so than repeating the work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As Musselman LLC points out, your Notepad++ configuration *may* be setup to perform an automatic backup, so check there first.

Your local C: 'desktop' may vary from the 'desktop' configured by your network admins. Sounds like you were using **C:\Users\**...your ID...**\Desktop**. But just to be sure, also check your network config'd 'desktop' by trying **%Homeshare%\Desktop**

Also, this Testing.txt file is not in the list of Recent files in Notepad++? Are other recent files in that list, but not Testing.txt?

Comment: Nice, thanks, but no it wasn't in the recent file list, or any of my profiles, nor in the backup path mentioned above. Even Windows' own 'Recent Files' couldn't find it, but thank you for your helpful input- turns out the files were being moved away deliberately to prevent 'forgetful' sysadmins dropping secrets all over the place!